# Updating Json Data for angular-flexslider breaks on 'removeSlide'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem: My json object is updating, but the slider does not update for all resorts. It should be updating as the json object changes but sometimes does not.

For the resorts (image collections) that do not update, it gives me an error: "cannot read property 'element' of undefined and breaks on angular-flexslider.js line 104. I cannot find any relation with the resorts that are giving me this error vs the ones that do not.

Summary of my script: I'm using angular-flexslider with a slider sync. I have a service that grabs image data and sends it to the controller. The controller picks it up and runs reorganize(), which takes the object it is given and reformats it into an array that flexslider supports.

This object needs to be updated as the images are updated. I have a dropdown that allows users to change the resort and I want the slider to reflect those changes.

Here is my code

JS:

```
resortModule.controller('galleryController', ['$scope', 'locaService', function($scope, locaService) {
    //object to receive images
    $scope.images;
    //object used for image slider
    $scope.imagePaths = [];
    //variable that gives me resort ID
    $scope.resort;

    //restructures images array to work better with image slider
    $scope.reorganize= function(){
        $scope.imagePaths.length= 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.images.length; i++) {
            var obj= {custom: "assets/images/resorts/" + $scope.images[i].resort + "/gallery/" + $scope.images[i].file_name, thumbnail:"assets/images/resorts/" + $scope.images[i].resort + "/thumbnail/" + $scope.images[i].file_name}
            $scope.imagePaths.push(obj);
        }
    }
    //watches factory for updates to objects/ variables
    $scope.$on('imagesUpdated', function() {
        $scope.images = locaService.images;
        $scope.reorganize();
    });
    $scope.$on('resortUpdated', function() {
        $scope.resort = locaService.resort;
    });   
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<flex-slider slider-id="slider" flex-slide="image in imagePaths track by $index" animation="fade" animation-loop="false" sync="#carousel" slideshow="false" control-nav="false" prev-text="" next-text="" init-delay="100">
  <li>
    <img ng-src="{{image.custom}}" alt="Luxury Resort Rental Image">
  </li>
</flex-slider>
<flex-slider class="slides hide-tablet-down" slider-id="carousel" flex-slide="image in imagePaths track by $index" animation="slide" animation-loop="false" item-width="210" item-margin="5" as-nav-for="#slider" slideshow="false" prev-text="" next-text="" control-nav="false">
  <li>
    <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="Luxury Resort Rental Image">
  </li>
</flex-slider>
```

Does anyone have any insight on this error? Or what I might be doing wrong? I've been researching it all day but have only found this:
https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider/issues/53
and this:
https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider/pull/63
Which did nothing for me, but I might not have understood them entirely. I'm not a seasoned angular developer and I'm learning as I go along. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented out the following lines in the angular-flexslider.js and it seemed to fix the problem. Let me know if you have a better solution:

```
if ((toAdd.length === 1 && toRemove.length === 0) || toAdd.length === 0) { 

... 

return $scope.$evalAsync(function() { return slider.addSlide(item.element, idx); }); }); } return; }`
```